# Getting error "The operation was aborted" when using BatchRequest to add many courses with Google Classroom API

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-classroom

I am trying to build a small script that can add many courses in Google Classroom.

I am using C# for this, and I used the following 2 references to get me started on this:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch

When I add them one by one using the API it works really fine and without any issue, however when I try to use the BatchRequest method as indicated in the link above, I start to get things to go wrong.

First of all let's assume I'm adding a set of 50 classes, when I run the code, only 3 or 4 of them get added, the then I receive an error message for the rest.

The error is only as shown below in the image...

[image]

I have no idea what is this about and I cannot understand the reason for this...

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
using Google.Apis.Classroom.v1;
using Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GSuite_ClassroomManager
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/classroom.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomCourses };
        static string ApplicationName = "Classroom API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //StartMultipleThread();
            buildCourses();
        }

        static void buildCourses()
        {
            //UserCredential credential;
            string Exepath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string currDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Exepath);
            string jsonFile = currDirectory + @"\credentials.json";
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonFile).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser("me");
            var courses = new List<Course>();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Authorized successfully...");
            // Create Classroom API service.
            var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            for (var counter=0; counter < 50; counter++)
            {
                CourseAlias alias = new CourseAlias
                {
                    Alias = "d:test0018"+counter.ToString()
                };

                var body = new Course
                {
                    Name = "Test course new 18 "+counter.ToString(),
                    Id = alias.Alias,
                    OwnerId = "me",
                    DescriptionHeading = "Welcome to Test course new " + counter.ToString()+"!",
                    Description = "This is a testing course number " + counter.ToString(),
                    CourseState = "ACTIVE"
                };

                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Creating Test course 3...");
                courses.Add(body);

                //alias = service.Courses.Aliases.Create(alias, body.Id).Execute();
            }

            var batch = new BatchRequest(service, "https://classroom.googleapis.com/batch");
            BatchRequest.OnResponse<Course> callback = (course,error,i,message) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Failed to create new course with the following error..: {0}", error.Message);
                }
                //else
                //{
                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", course.Name, course.Id, course.Id);
                //}
            };
            foreach (var course in courses)
            {
                var item = new Course
                {
                    Name = course.Name,
                    Id = course.Id,
                    OwnerId = course.OwnerId,
                    DescriptionHeading = course.DescriptionHeading,
                    Description = course.Description,
                    CourseState = course.CourseState
                };
                var result = service.Courses.Create(item);
                batch.Queue<Course>(result, callback);
                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", result.Name, result.Id, course.Id);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(batch.ExecuteAsync());

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Retrieving list of courses");
            // Define request parameters.
            CoursesResource.ListRequest request = service.Courses.List();
            request.PageSize = 100;

            // List courses.
            ListCoursesResponse response = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Listing courses:");
            if (response.Courses != null && response.Courses.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var course in response.Courses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", course.Name, course.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - No courses found.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Done.");
            Console.Read();
        }
     }
}
```

I have been attempting to troubleshoot this however I did not get to any result. I know about the 1000 requests limit for this however I'm only running 50 and at max I got to 300 courses to be added only...

I am authorized properly and I can create courses when I use the normal one by one method, however with the large number of courses I have it is going to take forever if I don't use batches...

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot and find out what's going on?

EDIT-
So I changed the code and used 5 threads to do the calls and add the courses, but the process is still very slow and it is going at the speed as if I'm just looping through the items one by one...

This is the new code for the threads:

```cs
    static private void buildCourses()
        {
            //UserCredential credential;
            string Exepath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string currDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Exepath);
            string jsonFile = currDirectory + @"\credentials.json";
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonFile).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser("me");
            var courses = new List<Course>();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Authorized successfully...");
            // Create Classroom API service.
            var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            for (var counter=0; counter < 500; counter++)
            {
                CourseAlias alias = new CourseAlias
                {
                    Alias = "d:test0476"+counter.ToString()
                };

                var body = new Course
                {
                    Name = "Test course new 476 "+counter.ToString(),
                    Id = alias.Alias,
                    OwnerId = "me",
                    DescriptionHeading = "Welcome to Test course new " + counter.ToString()+"!",
                    Description = "This is a testing course number " + counter.ToString(),
                    CourseState = "ACTIVE"
                };

                courses.Add(body);
            }


            var itemsCout = courses.Count;
            var threadCount = 5;
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread {0}", (0 + 1).ToString());
                for (var i = 0; i < itemsCout; i = i + threadCount)
                {
                    var item = new Course
                    {
                        Name = courses[i].Name,
                        Id = courses[i].Id,
                        OwnerId = courses[i].OwnerId,
                        DescriptionHeading = courses[i].DescriptionHeading,
                        Description = courses[i].Description,
                        CourseState = courses[i].CourseState
                    };

                    var alias = courses[i].Id;

                    item = service.Courses.Create(item).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", item.Name, item.Id, alias);
                }
            });

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread {0}", (1 + 1).ToString());
                for (var i = 1; i < itemsCout; i = i + threadCount)
                {
                    var item = new Course
                    {
                        Name = courses[i].Name,
                        Id = courses[i].Id,
                        OwnerId = courses[i].OwnerId,
                        DescriptionHeading = courses[i].DescriptionHeading,
                        Description = courses[i].Description,
                        CourseState = courses[i].CourseState
                    };

                    var alias = courses[i].Id;

                    item = service.Courses.Create(item).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", item.Name, item.Id, alias);
                }
            });

            Thread thread3 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread {0}", (2 + 1).ToString());
                for (var i = 2; i < itemsCout; i = i + threadCount)
                {
                    var item = new Course
                    {
                        Name = courses[i].Name,
                        Id = courses[i].Id,
                        OwnerId = courses[i].OwnerId,
                        DescriptionHeading = courses[i].DescriptionHeading,
                        Description = courses[i].Description,
                        CourseState = courses[i].CourseState
                    };

                    var alias = courses[i].Id;

                    item = service.Courses.Create(item).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", item.Name, item.Id, alias);
                }
            });

            Thread thread4 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread {0}", (3 + 1).ToString());
                for (var i = 3; i < itemsCout; i = i + threadCount)
                {
                    var item = new Course
                    {
                        Name = courses[i].Name,
                        Id = courses[i].Id,
                        OwnerId = courses[i].OwnerId,
                        DescriptionHeading = courses[i].DescriptionHeading,
                        Description = courses[i].Description,
                        CourseState = courses[i].CourseState
                    };

                    var alias = courses[i].Id;

                    item = service.Courses.Create(item).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", item.Name, item.Id, alias);
                }
            });

            Thread thread5 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread {0}", (4 + 1).ToString());
                for (var i = 4; i < itemsCout; i = i + threadCount)
                {
                    var item = new Course
                    {
                        Name = courses[i].Name,
                        Id = courses[i].Id,
                        OwnerId = courses[i].OwnerId,
                        DescriptionHeading = courses[i].DescriptionHeading,
                        Description = courses[i].Description,
                        CourseState = courses[i].CourseState
                    };

                    var alias = courses[i].Id;

                    item = service.Courses.Create(item).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created new course: {0} with ID {1}, and alias of {2}...", item.Name, item.Id, alias);
                }
            });

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
            thread3.Start();
            thread4.Start();
            thread5.Start();

            thread1.Join();
            thread2.Join();
            thread3.Join();
            thread4.Join();
            thread5.Join();

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Done.");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Is there any possible way to speed this up? Or it is just the API that's so slow?

Thanks all!

Comment: isnt the batch limit 5? why are you bothering with batching exactly.   Its a pain to set up and it doesn't save you anything besides the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: @DaImTo would it be better then to use multiple threads and do normal requests?